# How to chat with other using same app in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, chat

i have a problem that

chat with others who are login in my iphone application
how it possible , are there any apps using same concept ,please help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your problem specifically? Do you have any code samples? There are plenty of apps that utilise intra-app messaging functionality.

Answer (score 2):

http://quickblox.com/modules/chat/
OR
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/

Try using that, it's almost an App within an App.. means you don't have to work all the code out :)